# Can't handle a go routine deadloock

Tags: go, broadcast, goroutine

I am trying to broadcast a message to a channel, I just want it to send 5 messages. but I always get this error :
**fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!**

my code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"

    broadcast "github.com/dustin/go-broadcast"
    "github.com/pwaller/barrier"
)

//Message boradcasted
type Message struct {
    y string
    x int
}

var w sync.WaitGroup
var bar barrier.Barrier

func main() {

    b := broadcast.NewBroadcaster(100)

    w.Add(1)
    go workerOne(b)

    d := Message{"message :", 0}

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            d.x = i
            log.Printf("Sending %v", d)
            b.Submit(d)
        }
        <-bar.Barrier()
        b.Close()
    }()
    w.Wait()
}

func workerOne(b broadcast.Broadcaster) {
    ch := make(chan interface{})
    b.Register(ch)

    for {
        v, ok := <-ch
        if ok {
            log.Printf("workerOne() reading : %v", v)
        } else {
            log.Printf("i am here")
            close(ch)
            b.Unregister(ch)
            bar.Fall()
            w.Done()
            return
        }
    }
}
```

the output :

```
2019/12/26 20:34:11 Sending {message : 0}
2019/12/26 20:34:11 Sending {message : 1}
2019/12/26 20:34:11 Sending {message : 2}
2019/12/26 20:34:11 Sending {message : 3}
2019/12/26 20:34:11 Sending {message : 4}
2019/12/26 20:34:11 workerOne() reading : {message : 0}
2019/12/26 20:34:11 workerOne() reading : {message : 1}
2019/12/26 20:34:11 workerOne() reading : {message : 2}
2019/12/26 20:34:11 workerOne() reading : {message : 3}
2019/12/26 20:34:11 workerOne() reading : {message : 4}
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x59f530)
        C:/Go/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x40
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x59f528)
        C:/Go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x6c
main.main()
        C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/work/demos/Design pattern/broadcast/broadcast.go:38 +0x107

goroutine 19 [select]:
github.com/dustin/go-broadcast.(*broadcaster).run(0xc000060420)
        D:/gocode/src/github.com/dustin/go-broadcast/broadcaster.go:39 +0x10f
created by github.com/dustin/go-broadcast.NewBroadcaster
        D:/gocode/src/github.com/dustin/go-broadcast/broadcaster.go:64 +0x103

goroutine 20 [chan receive]:
main.workerOne(0x4f1de0, 0xc000060420)
        C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/work/demos/Design pattern/broadcast/broadcast.go:46 +0xcd
created by main.main
        C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/work/demos/Design pattern/broadcast/broadcast.go:25 +0x8e

goroutine 21 [chan receive]:
main.main.func1(0xc000060440, 0x4f1de0, 0xc000060420)
        C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/work/demos/Design pattern/broadcast/broadcast.go:35 +0x168
created by main.main
        C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/work/demos/Design pattern/broadcast/broadcast.go:29 +0xf7
exit status 2
```

I tried everything but it doesn't go throw condition !ok in workerOne() function to close the channel and end waiting, but still have the same error

Comment: You have one worker and one channel but you've got all this extra stuff - what are you trying to do here? Why are you using `broadcast`? Why are you using `barrier` (which says on its own readme that it's deprecated)?

Comment: Generally speaking a deadlock happens because all of the goroutines are waiting on other goroutines, which means none of them can ever proceed. The use of these third-party libraries over built-in langauge constructs makes it harder to tell what exactly is causing this and what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Adrian i am learning broadcast to use it later on my project so i am trying to understand it first and it was an issue happen when b.Submit(d) end brodcast and  close before workerOne() function recieve all message so i used the Barrier to prevent it from closing before  workerOne() function get all message

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using libraries that are deprecated. Looking at broadcast, I can't say I would recommend it either; in an effort to save maybe one or two dozen lines of code, it sacrifices type-safety, which is a pretty big price to pay for very little benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Adrian noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492335/cant-handle-a-go-routine-deadloock#comment105159246_59492335), the [`barrier`](https://github.com/pwaller/barrier) package you are using is deprecated in favor of Go's included [`context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) package.  You should use [`context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) instead. ( The [`broadcast`](https://github.com/dustin/go-broadcast) package you are using is not really doing you any good either, at the moment.)

The immediate problem seems pretty obvious, though: the (single) goroutine running `workerOne` reads from a channel, and only if the channel is *closed* (so that `ok` becomes `false`) does it call `bar.Fall()` to drop the barrier.  Meanwhile, the (single) goroutine running the anonymous sender function:

```
go func() {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        d.x = i
        log.Printf("Sending %v", d)
        b.Submit(d)
    }
    <-bar.Barrier()
    b.Close()
}()
```

submits five items through the [`broadcast`](https://github.com/dustin/go-broadcast) package's (very) simple message pub/sub interface, then waits for the barrier to fall.  The only goroutine that will *drop* the barrier—think of it as the only other [gopher](https://blog.golang.org/gopher) that can rescue you here—is the one running `workerOne`.  He is, right now, waiting in channel-receive:

```
    v, ok := <-ch
```

You, in your main goroutine, are waiting via your `sync.WaitGroup` variable:

```
w.Wait()
```

The gopher running the anonymous sender function is waiting:

```
    <-bar.Barrier()
```

Who—which of these three gophers running or waiting in various Go routines—is going to signal, to the gopher in the anonymous sender, the `v, ok := <-ch` should get a `!ok` result?  The only one who *could* is the gopher running `workerOne`, but he's stuck.

The [`broadcast`](https://github.com/dustin/go-broadcast) package won't ever close your channel for you.  Unregistering a channel just removes it from the broadcaster's output channels, which leaves the unregistered channel open; and closing the broadcaster entirely effectively just unregisters all channels, again leaving them open.  So if you want your channel closed, you would have to do that yourself, somewhere else.

Alternatively, you could modify your `workerOne` so that it doesn't depend on the channel being closed.  For instance, your variable `d` has an `x int` and a `y string`; you could pick one or both of these and decide that a string value reading "drop the barrier"—perhaps with some particular `int` value as well—means "call `bar.Fall()` now".  If you do this, you're getting even less out of these two nonstandard packages, though.